# how to convert id, value array list to [id]:[value] type object

Tags: javascript, object

How to convert objects list like:

```
[{id:3, value:"value1"}, {id:4, value:"value2"}]
```

to

```
 {3:"value1", 4:"value2"}
```

I am not sure this is Best Solution. But work.

```js
var list = [{id:3, value:"value1"}, {id:4, value:"value2"}]
var result = Object.assign({}, ...list.map((obj, index)=>{
  return {[obj.id]:obj.value};
}))
console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you have working code that you would like to improve on this question might be better placed at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Your current solution is already a one-liner, or could be formatted as such - especially if you changed it to use the short arrow function syntax without the `{}` and `return`.

Comment: It work well. If you know more best solution please share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "best". But when I tried your solution, `reduce()` solution and simple `for` loop in [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/arrtohash/1) the good old `for` loop is the fastest :)

[image]

```js
var list = [{id:3, value:"value1"}, {id:4, value:"value2"}];
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
  result[list[i].id] = list[i].value;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Fastest method is very needed to me for lot of data processing. :)

Comment: I will use traditional method . Thank you.

Comment: @riguangzheng You're welcome. It's often the simplest solution that works the best. Although `Object.assign` and `reduce` have their beauty too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for objects with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
var array = [{ id: 3, value: "value1" }, { id: 4, value: "value2" }],
    result = Object.assign(...array.map(({ id, value }) => ({ [id]: value })));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank your reply. If we have to validate schema of object How we can solve this?. I need to verify of input list because i have to deal it from mongodb collection

Answer (score 0):

Reduce will solve your problem:

```js
var list = [{id: "foo", value: "bar"}, {"id":"baz", value:"bad"}];
var result = list.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.id] = item.value;
    return obj
}, {});
console.log(result);
```