# How can I convert an Array of Key Value pairs to object with values of first array as keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My backend is returning the data as below.

```
   var permissions = [{"PermCode":"BOF","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"CM","IsvalidPerm":false},{"PermCode":"CV","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"DAS","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"RPT","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"VM","IsvalidPerm":true}]
```

How can I convert this to an Objectof Object as below

```
{BOF:true,CM:true, ...}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why the array in the result? what have you tried?

Comment: In angular I need to enable and disable things based on the user permissions. But my backend is returning the data with the column names.  I need it as an array of Objects with true/false status.

Comment: Yes I realized now. I need Object not the array. Corrected my question.

Comment: please close as dupe for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133075/how-to-convert-id-value-array-list-to-idvalue-type-object/

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365354/how-to-convert-json-output-to-array-in-jquery/

Answer (score 4):

You could use some ES6 syntax, using `Object.assign`, spread syntax, computed properties, and then it really gets very *functional programming* style:

```js
var permissions = [{"PermCode":"BOF","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"CM","IsvalidPerm":false},{"PermCode":"CV","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"DAS","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"RPT","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"VM","IsvalidPerm":true}];

const result = Object.assign(...permissions.map(
    ({PermCode, IsvalidPerm}) => ({[PermCode]: IsvalidPerm})
));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why would you use `Object.assign` ?

Comment: It just is easy for converting an array of objects to one merged object.

Comment: my bad, didn't see his edit to ask for an object and not an array of object. Although I still prefer `reduce` ...

Comment: totally, +1 for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Altough you can find the answer in the documentation of `Array` (disclaimer: it's `map`), the syntax is a bit tricky for a one-liner.

Here you go :

```js
const data = [
  {"PermCode":"BOF","IsvalidPerm":true},
  {"PermCode":"CM","IsvalidPerm":false},
  {"PermCode":"CV","IsvalidPerm":true},
  {"PermCode":"DAS","IsvalidPerm":true},
  {"PermCode":"RPT","IsvalidPerm":true},
  {"PermCode":"VM","IsvalidPerm":true}
];

const formatted = data.map(item => ({[item.PermCode]: item.IsvalidPerm}));

console.log(formatted);
```

As for your edit, if you want to create an object, use `reduce` instead :

```js
const data = [
  {"PermCode":"BOF","IsvalidPerm":true},
  {"PermCode":"CM","IsvalidPerm":false},
  {"PermCode":"CV","IsvalidPerm":true},
  {"PermCode":"DAS","IsvalidPerm":true},
  {"PermCode":"RPT","IsvalidPerm":true},
  {"PermCode":"VM","IsvalidPerm":true}
];

const formatted = data.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.PermCode]: curr.IsvalidPerm }), {});

console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please always show your attempt in OP so that we get to know which direction you were moving..

You can use "Array.map" and "Object.assign" like below

```js
var permissions = [{"PermCode":"BOF","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"CM","IsvalidPerm":false},{"PermCode":"CV","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"DAS","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"RPT","IsvalidPerm":true},{"PermCode":"VM","IsvalidPerm":true}]

let result = Object.assign(...permissions.map(d => ({ [d.PermCode]: d.IsvalidPerm})))

console.log(result)
```